# C# Using VB6-Dll - AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, vb6, dllimport, access-violation

I try to use a VB6 DLL in a C# Program. But I allways get a AccessViolationException. Maybe you can tell me what Im doing wrong.
I created a Test-VB6-DLL like in this tutorial: 
       http://oreilly.com/pub/a/windows/2005/04/26/create_dll.html

Then I tried to use this DLL dynamically like in this Post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments

But also if I try it by using [DLLImport]. I allways run into the AccessViolationException.
Maybe someone can give me a hint.

regards
viktor

P.S.: What I was able to do is to create a reference to an existing DLL. But this approach has the disadvantage, that I have to update all the references if the DLL is updated. And this will happen (more or less) open because to dlls are part of a softwareproject that is under developmen. Maybe there is a possibility to update the references without to need to recompile the C# program?

---

@MarkJ: No - binary compatibility brought no success.

Here are the sources:
The VB6-Dll:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Increment(var As Integer) As Integer
   If Not IsNumeric(var) Then Err.Raise 5

   Increment = var + 1
End Function
```

And here the C# code that tries to use the VB6 Dll:

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(String DllName);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, byte[] procedureName);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr pDll = LoadLibrary(@"P:\dev\Path\to\TestProjekt.dll");

        string x = "Increment";         
        Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        byte[] b = e.GetBytes(x);

        IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = GetProcAddress(pDll, b);
        Increment inc = Increment)Marshal.
                GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall,
                                              typeof(Increment));

        int a = inc(5);    // <---- Here the AccessViolationException is thrown

        return;
    }
}
```

In the meantime I have read any doc I could find but still I don't habe any idea why this ist not working *grgrgrgrgr*

regards
viktor

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm using .Net 3.5 ;-)

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  How wrong is completely unguessable from your question, you didn't post any snippet to look at.

Comment: You probably need to use binary compatibility in your VB6 dll project

Comment: Why not call the VB6 DLL through COM? Much, much, easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your `byte[] b` has no terminating null, so isn't a valid unmanaged `LPCSTR`. I don't understand why you are fiddling about trying to encode the method name by hand, instead of declaring GetProcAddress like this and having the Framework interop code take care of the marshalling for you:

```
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string procedureName);
```

You must check the return value (`pAddressOfFunctionToCall`). When it is`IntPtr.Zero` as I believe you are getting, because your lpProcName argument to `GetProcAddress` is wrong, then attempting to call through its Delegate wrapper will always give an `AccessViolationException`.

Also, don't omit to call `FreeLibrary` on the module handle when you are done.

Comment: I have put the misssing code from the deleted answer into the question. It was actually a moderator who deleted the answer, not the OP. Not sure why.